# BLE background operation issue

Tags: ios, xcode, multithreading, bluetooth-lowenergy, background-process

I am trying to transfer a firmware file from my app to a wearable hardware.
it takes about some time and when my app goes in background or the lock button is pressed the firmware transfer process discontinues.

ideally it should continue to transfer the firmware. I am using this method to continue the process in background and also also have declared the support for the background modes.

```
  - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    bgTask = 0;
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" expirationHandler:^{
        // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
        // stopped or ending the task outright.
        //[application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.

        //[application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
```

}

This method is not able to do the task.

However if I use this method in Appdelegate - didFinishLaunchingWithOptions it works.

But there is a trade off with putting this piece of code in the above method i.e If I am not transferring the firmware and the app goes in background then after 3 mins this piece of code removes the app and bluetooth connection breaks.

If I am not using this method at all, then the connection remains until it is broken manually but background transfer does not happen.

I have to keep both the operations simultaneously. Please suggest something as I have been for many days on this particular problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the peripheral send a message when it is ready for the next block - ie. Are you using writeWithResponse?  Alternatively, if this method works, why don't you simply set a boolean in the app delegate that indicates if you are updating firmware and don't start the background task if it isn't needed?

Comment: @paulw :-  yes the peripheral sends the acknowledgement back when I send it a data packet. Also I cant seem to understand how to set the flag and set it true in the -didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method on starting the firmware upgrade. Also If I write that block of code in a separate method, then how do I get the "application" object as it is available to me in -didFinish method [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler]. Please clear the doubt

Comment: If your peripheral supports writeWithNotify then you should be able to use the standard Bluetooth background mode and you don't need a background task

Comment: how to check for the fact that my peripheral supports this method or not? In my code I am using this method to receive the response whenever I write the data onto then peripheral.                  (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didWriteValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
[peripheral setNotifyValue:TRUE forCharacteristic: ];
} Also this method:-                                                                                         didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error

Comment: As long as you get a call to either of those methods your Bluetooth code can operate in the background with the Bluetooth Central background mode - you don't need a specific background task

Comment: Yeah, it is the same info I had but it doesn't go that way somehow. I dont know the reason but without implementing that method I am not able to transfer the firmware in background.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74548/discussion-between-paulw11-and-shikhar-varshney).

Comment: @Paulw11 can we chat now?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your application using `BackgroundModes`
and remove all the codes from `didEnterInbackground`